# What the benefits of summer school when working on masters degree?

Tags: graduate-school, summer-school

I have recently started my graduate studies and I am still new to some of it. I always worked in the summer during my undergrad, but I've heard that working in the summer while working on  a masters isn't what I am supposed to do. I can believe this, but I am confused. What are the benefits to taking a few classes in the summer? I don't need to retake anything because I failed or need the requirement, because I am just starting out. I need some advice on this.

Comment: _I've heard that working in the summer while working on a masters isn't what I am supposed to do._ - Heard from who? What did they say you _should_ do in the summer? (Internship? Research? Classes?)

Comment: Do you really mean a "summer school", or just "taking courses over the summer"? Summer schools usually last for a few days or so, and you listen to talks, maybe do something hands-on, socialize, and stuff like that.

Comment: @mrm I mean taking courses over the summer. And ff524, I heard that I should take more classes instead of working like I used to during my undergrad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trouble with "what you're supposed to do" is that it often applies to some imaginary archetypal student or, worse, students of a very specific class and privilege. Not all students have the means to go without working, to help pay their own way through school. Academia is *just* starting to wake up to this fact, thanks to the consciousness raising of folks like Sarah Kendzior.

If you can find a part-job related to your field of study, then it's definitely OK for you to work over summer break. I was able to do this while in my MLS program.

If you are unable to find work related to your field of study--and if you aren't involved in student organizations or showing that you're otherwise productive in your "non-school" hours by starting to attend conferences, write papers, etc--then I could see it being a drawback to have a job in your "off" time.